# WPF MVVM: Update label depending on Textbox input (2nd Attempt)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Okay so I've now got a more specific question.

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the value (bool) of a label when two Textboxes are no longer empty. I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work even though it seems very straight forward.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Please see below my code.

Model (Person.cs)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeUI.Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName + " " + _lastName;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return _lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel (PersonViewModel.cs)

```cs
using PracticeUI.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PracticeUI.ViewModel
{
    public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private Person _newPerson = new Person();
        private ICommand _addPerson;
        public Person NewPerson
        {
            get
            {
                return _newPerson;
            }
            set
            {
                _newPerson = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NewPerson");
            }
        }

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            _PersonList.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Barratt" });
            _PersonList.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Harriet", LastName = "Hammond" });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Person> _PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList
        {
            get
            {
                return _PersonList;
            }
            set
            {
                _PersonList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PersonList");
                OnPropertyChanged("AddPersonCanExecute");
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddPersonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addPerson == null)
                {
                    _addPerson = new RelayCommand(p => this.AddPersonCanExecute, p => this.AddPerson());
                }
                return _addPerson;
            }
        }
        public bool AddPersonCanExecute
        {
            get
            {
                return _newPerson.FirstName != string.Empty || _newPerson.LastName != string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public void AddPerson()
        {
            _PersonList.Add(new Person() { FirstName = _newPerson.FirstName, LastName = _newPerson.LastName });
            OnPropertyChanged("PersonList");
        }
    }
}
```

View (MainWindow.xaml)

```cs
<Window x:Class="PracticeUI.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:PracticeUI.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ViewModel:PersonViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=PersonList}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="200" Margin="0 0 0 20">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Label Content="First Name:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=NewPerson.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="2" Height="40" Width="200" Margin="10 5"/>
        <Label Content="First Name:" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=NewPerson.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="2" Height="40" Width="200" Margin="10 5"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=AddPersonCommand}" Content="Add Person" Width="120" Height="30" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=AddPersonCanExecute, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename `PersonViewModel` to `MainViewModel`. It's not a viewmodel that represents a person, it's your main viewmodel for the whole program. It has a whole collection of `Person`; how is it one person? It isn't. Naming your classes well makes it much easier to keep track of what's what. We'll be renaming `Person` to `PersonViewModel` because it needs to be a viewmodel also, and it does actually represent a person.

You want the UI to look at the value of `AddPersonCanExecute` whenever there's a change in the value of `NewPerson.FirstName` or `NewPerson.LastName`.

What can cause those values to change?

One way is that `NewPerson` can change. So:

```
public Person NewPerson
{
    get
    {
        return _newPerson;
    }
    set
    {
        _newPerson = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AddPersonCanExecute));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewPerson));
    }
}
```

Another way is that the user can type a new value into the textboxes bound to the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties of `NewPerson`. Then you and the UI are out of luck, because `Person` isn't a viewmodel. It never raises any events when its properties change. So make it a viewmodel.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //  Copy your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here from your main viewmodel
    //  Make your main viewmodel inherit from ViewModelBase
}

//  Formerly PersonViewModel
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //  We need this to be the actual type because we'll need to be calling 
    //  RaiseCanExecuteChanged() on it. Or whatever equivalent. 
    private RelayCommand _addPerson;

    //  All the stuff PersonViewModel had.
    //  Stuff
    //  Stuff
    //  Stuff
}

//  Remember, your old PersonViewModel is now named MainViewModel. This is the class 
//  that you used to call Person. 
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName + " " + _lastName;
        }
        //  No empty set, not ever. Somebody will try to set FullName and the compiler 
        //  will let him think it worked. But nothing will change. That's a bug. 
        //set { }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            //  Do the same for LastName. Careful you don't pass nameof(FirstName) 
            // over there. 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }
```

Now the UI knows when those properties change, but the main viewmodel still doesn't. But now that we have notifications from `Person`, that's solvable. We have to rewrite NewPerson again:

```
private PersonViewModel _newPerson = null;
public PersonViewModel NewPerson
{
    get { return _newPerson; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _newPerson)
        {
            //  Take the handler off the old NewPerson, if any. 
            if (_newPerson != null)
            {
                _newPerson.PropertyChanged -= NewPerson_PropertyChanged;
            }
            _newPerson = value;
            if (_newPerson != null)
            {
                _newPerson.PropertyChanged += NewPerson_PropertyChanged;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NewPerson));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AddPersonCanExecute));

            //  I don't know what your RelayCommand class looks like, but it should 
            //  provide some way to force it to raise its CanExecuteChanged event. 
            //  That's what the Button is waiting for to enable or disable itself. 
            _addPerson.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        }
    }
}

private void NewPerson_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case nameof(Person.FirstName):
        case nameof(Person.LastName):
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AddPersonCanExecute));
            AddPerson
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Another point: Don't make your viewmodel a resource. It's not breaking your code, but it serves no purpose and creates extra work for you.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:PersonViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- remove it from here -->
</Window.Resources>
```

Now for all controls belonging to the Window itself, all your bindings can look like this:

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding NewPerson.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
    Grid.Row="2" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Height="40" Width="200" Margin="10 5"
    />
```

Get rid of Mode=TwoWay on TextBox.Text; that property will cause bindings on it to be TwoWay by default. Keep `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` only on TextBox.Text: That will cause the textbox to update the viewmodel on every keystroke, instead of the default behavior of updating the viewmodel property only when the textbox loses focus. You don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the command binding or the Label.Content binding, because those properties *cannot ever* update the viewmodel property. They're OneWay by default, and by the nature of what they do.

Comment: Thanks so much for your critique and commentary! This has really helped me on my WPF journey. I was playing around with data context both in the Code-Behind and in XAML -  thats why I didn't set the data context to the PersonViewModel. The aim was to progress towards using two view models in one window. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#specifying-the-binding-source

Comment: @Teebee15 A window (or whatever) has one viewmodel. *However*, that one viewmodel can have any number of properties that return *other* viewmodels (and they can have their own "child" viewmodel properties, ad infinitum). My day job is maintaining an application with 150+ viewmodels and that's how we do it. That resource thing *hides* that viewmodel from the others and makes it impossible for the viewmodels to communicate in a normal way. It's one case of an anti-pattern practiced by people new to WPF: They think the application is a tree of *views*. It isn't in WPF. It's a tree of viewmodels.

Comment: @Teebee15 The views don't need to know about each other except for direct children in XAML; all they do is display the state of viewmodels. The critical thing is for each viewmodel to create and manage its own child viewmodels. When you hide viewmodels from each other by creating them in your views, you invariably end up having to resort to preposterous Rube Goldberg workarounds to do anything useful. I'm shocked and horrified that anybody at MS is publishing something like that example at this late date. It's malpractice. OK, sermon over.